# Ionic2 Serve Issue on Mac

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Have some issues when i try start ionic serve in mac terminal.

some of error message

> ionic-conference-app@ ionic:serve /Users/web/Desktop/AppDePrueba/ionic-conference-app
>   ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

sh: ionic-app-scripts: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the newest version of ionic-app-scripts (1.1.4 as of today) in your package.json.

Then delete your node_modules folder, run `npm install` and try again.

If that doesn't work you might need to reinstall ionic. Can you run `ionic info` and post it's output here?